Transforming an assertive sentence into an Interrogative sentence
I am confused in option A and C most suitable by grammar would be C but the question looks A

Question: Select the most appropriate option to transform the following assertive sentence to an interrogative sentence.
Vijaya is the new English professor.
(A) Isn't Vijaya the new English professor ?
(B) Wasn't Vijaya the new English professor ?
(C) Who is the new English professor ?
(D) How is Vijaya the new English professor?
(E) Question not attempted

This is from the official exam paper of clerk in Rajasthan LDC (Lower Division Clerk) held on 11 August 2024. I am checking my answers before the official answer key released.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The correct answer creates the cleanest exchange, which is the imaginary (F):

Is Vijaya the new English professor?

But the best option available is (A), because the transformation must at a minimum retain Vijaya and the new English professor. And be available. If I took the test, I'd go with (E) for hating all the crummy attempts.
Pro tip — While (A) is not precise by introducing the negative, no MC questions ask for precise "right answers," only the best or "most appropriate option." Even in math questions where options 1/3 and 2/6 can both be correct, 1/3 is the better answer for being reduced (simplified).
Note also that when converting statement to interrogative, you are not writing a script of possible prequels to the current story. The assertion as stated must convert as is:

"It's 4AM" becomes "Is it 4AM?" not "What time is it?"


The positive helping verb becomes negative when you add a question tag and vice versa.

Vijaya is the new English professor.
Vijaya is the new English professor, isn't she?

Some grammar books in India follow the same rule for changing assertive to interrogative.  Explanation in Byjus website. Interestingly, a similar example is given.

If the assertive sentence is positive, make the question negative.
For example, a sentence such as:
'Lorraine is the new English teacher', the interrogative sentence will be:
'Isn't Lorraine the new English teacher?
If the assertive sentence is negative, the interrogative sentence should be a positive question.

So, the correct answer is A. This is the accepted answer in India

(A) Isn't Vijaya the new English professor?

However if you are in an anglophone speaking country, you have to answer it differently:

Is Vijaya the new English teacher?

Both UK and Indian website (giving different answers) given below.

BYJU'S: Transformation of Assertive Sentences to Interrogative Sentences - Rules and Examples

proofreading.co.uk Detailed Explanation: Converting Assertive to Interrogative Sentences



I asked the same question to some Indian local professor and they replied this: [Option 'A' is the correct transformation.
[ The candidate has been asked to transform the sentence into interrogative rather than to change the sentence.
[ Vijaya is the new English professor.

Isn't Vijaya the new English professor? (Transformed into interrogative)
Who is the new English professor? (Changed into interrogative)
[In transformation we stick to the meaning of the said sentence, but when we change the sentence, meaning also changes.


That is the expected answer. I have given the link.. If you want marks follow your professors advice.  There is no option without the negative.https://byjus.com/english/transformation-of-assertive-sentences-into-interrogative-sentences/#:~:text=If%20the%20assertive%20sentence%20is,should%20be%20a%20positive%20question.

Actually i am new to English math exchange site. I use mathematics exchange for a long time. Do you work for byju? Hiw can I see your explanation?

I don't work for Byjus. I don't agree with their answer either. I follow the UK method. For question tag making negative is correct. I have attached both the links.

Select the most appropriate option to transform the following declarative assertive sentence to an interrogative sentence.

Declarative: Vijaya is the new English professor.

Interrogative: Is Vijaya the new English professor?


The answers sugge
(A) Isn't Vijaya the new English professor ?
(B) Wasn't Vijaya the new English professor ?
(C) Who is the new English professor ?
(D) How is Vijaya the new English professor?
(E) Question not attempted
Answer not given. All those sentences are fine grammatically but they don't answer the very easy question of the given sentence.
